# Which set did this Technic assembly come from?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

*I posted a week or so ago and had great  success identifying a LEGO Star Wars set which is now completed. 
So.. thought is would try again.* Can anyone help me identify what this could be?

Comment: Ahh brilliant, this site and the support is fantastic! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

According to BrickLink there are only 4 sets with the arched element in it in Dark Bluish Gray.
From those only [8435 Technic 4WD](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8435-1#T=S&O=) seems to fit:

[image]

Comment: I have this set and can confirm.